# In Google Sheets, subtract string "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ET" from =now(). How to convert string to number?

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, time, timestamp

We have the string `2022-06-01 11:01:05 ET` in Google Sheets and we are looking to compute the difference between this string and `=now()`. We cannot simply subtract the cells because we cannot subtract a string from a number/date. How can we subtract and get the difference between timestamps (not just dates, precision to the hh:mm:ss would be useful.). The output we are looking for is a simple decimal number representing the time difference, that we can convert into minutes or seconds as needed.

Comment: You need to do this for just one string? Or do you need to convert many such strings in a column? In either case, what is the cell reference/range where your unprocessed data resides? (I prefer to write to write accurate formulas where possible rather than talking in generalities.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=(NOW()*1)-(1*REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(.*) "))
```

then:

```
=TEXT((NOW()*1)-(1*REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(.*) ")), "[h]:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 3):

See my comment to your original post. But as your post is written, you need to do this for only one cell. So assuming that cell is A2:

`=NOW()-REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(.+)\s\S+$")`

... then set the format of that output to **Duration**.

Understand that since the `NOW` function is volatile (constantly changing), the output will also constantly be changing. Hopefully, that is what you want and expect.

Comment: This is what I want and expect, yes. The purpose of this column is to see how out-of-date another column is.

Answer (score 0):

You mention:

> We have the string **`2022-06-01 11:01:05 ET`** in Google Sheets...

It is safer to use:

```
=NOW()-REGEXEXTRACT(B1, "(.*) ")+(x/24)
```

*(where `x=difference in time zones` and `B1` is the cell containing the sting)*

As an example, if your sheet's time zone is *"(GMT+00:00) London"*, `x` should be adjusted accordingly

[image]

#### WHY?

Both of the answers provided by Erik as well as player0 will work if and **only IF you are in the same time zone**.

Considering the fact though that you do mention that the time zone in your question is a string (meaning fixed) as well as it is quite common for a Google Sheet to be in a different time zone, **it is safer to use the above formula**.

Please have a look at [these times](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20220601T160100&p1=tz_est&p2=179&p3=136&p4=137&p5=tz_pst)